# “device is not defined” : Ionic/Cordova app - trying to collect device model/manufacturer

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed the cordova plugin 'cordova-plugin-device' and am trying to retrieve the device object to get the model and manufacturer for the device running my app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device

Currently my app is split into sections, my 'about' section controller looks like follows:

// coffeescript code

```
angular.module('aboutPageController', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.controller 'aboutPage',['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaDevice', ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaDevice) ->
$scope.aboutTxt = 'some text'
$ionicPlatform.ready ->
  $scope.$apply ->    
  $scope.aboutTxt = 'new text'
  device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice()
  console.log(device)
  deviceInformation = $ionicPlatform.device()
  $scope.aboutTxt = deviceInformation.model
  return
 return
return
]
```

My App

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/templates.js"></script>
```

I am currently getting the following error device

```
ReferenceError: device is not defined
```

in ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: device is not defined

Comment: Did you try `var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();` instead of `device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice()` ?

Comment: Sorry I did - this is my coffeescript code so it will automatically correct it to valid javascript when i run my gulp build command

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice, at which exact line is it failing ? (not  ionic.bundle.js:25642 but the actual code)

Comment: Sorry from the log 
ReferenceError: device is not defined
    at Object.getModel (ng-cordova.min.js:7)

Comment: What usually helps me solve this kind of error is to insert a `debugger;` one line above the error and trying to run the next line in the console. This way you'll be sure about the plugins being present and its methods.

Answer (score 2):

You must wait for cordova to send the `deviceready` event. Otherwise this Reference error will be coming. You should add an event Listener for `deviceready`.

This is my Understanding.